# Does the hreflang attr. make sense in <base>?

Tags: html, href, hreflang

Does a `hreflang` attribute make sense in the `<base>` element?
I thought about using this attribute, like:

```
<base href="example.com" target="_self" hreflang="de">
```

to let every link (`<a>` and `<link>`) inherit the value of `hreflang`.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation here](https://devdocs.io/html/attributes#hreflang-attribute), mentions that only `<a>`, `<area>`, `<link>` are the tags which make use of this attribute.

Comment: at least it would make sense to implement that feature, wouldn't you say so?